# How can it prints '?' in Java when I try to print char(-1)

Tags: java

I'm reading Java Puzzlers these days, in question 6, it mentioned the transformation in basic data types.
Then I want to have a try of convertting (-1) to char and print it. It should print the ascii code of -1, right? But there's no a character whose ascii is -1 and there's someone told me it should be 255 instead. And in fact it output '?', is there anyone can give me a reason?

Thank you, thank you all in Thanksgiving Day.

Comment: Ascii has a range of 0 to 255, therefore it will overflow. So if you take char 0 and add -1 it will go to 255, but if you take 255 and add 1 it will go to 0

Comment: @Quillion Java is not using ASCII but Unicode tables. But rest of your explanation is correct.

Comment: Refer this link, it's similar to your question: http://www.coderanch.com/t/265284/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/Explanation-required-negative-char-prints

Comment: @Pankaj, shouldn't be ascii contained in unicode?

Answer (score 2):

Putting -1 in a char will overflow it to 0xFFFF (because it's an [unsigned 16 bit value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).) [0xFFFF is a non-character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffff/index.htm), hence the `?`.

If the character produced by the overflow is not a non-character, it would show up fine:

```
char x = (char)-65500;
System.out.println(x); //Prints $
```

Same principle, only this time we've overflowed to a value that actually has a defined character attached to it (36, the dollar symbol.) Note there's no practical application of this - you never want to deliberately overflow a char by setting it to a negative value.

Comment: Thanks berry, I get it. BTW, though the result of char(-2) is '?', when I compare char(-1) with char(-2) or '?', it returns false, maybe they're different?

Comment: @Diansonn The result isn't actually a `?` per-se, the ascii code for that is 63. It's just that a question mark is used to represent a non character (which 0xFFFF is) in place of a real character (since it's a non-character, what else are you going to reference it by? It has to print something.) -2 wraps in a similar way to `0xFFFE`, a different undefined character. All equals is doing is comparing the underlying values, not whether the characters look the similar or the same - so it will of course return false.

Comment: SO, it's just a wrap. Every one with a different wrap.

Comment: @Diansonn Yes - since char is inherently unsigned, all negative numbers will wrap round to positive values.

Answer (score 1):

When you cast `-1` to a `char` you get the `65535` character as `char` is an unsigned 16-bit integer. Whenever you cast a larger integer to a 16-bit value the lower 16-bit are retained. This is an invalid character by definition and thus will always print as `?` or `<?>`

BTW `(char) 255` is a valid character.

Comment: Peter, as I know from Internet, when 0~127 cannot identify a word(e.g. a Chinese word), it turns to unicode such as utf-8, right? So ascii is contained in unicode. In utf-8 if the word need more than one byte, there would be 1 to 4 bit(s)'s '1' to mark how many bytes it needs, for example a two-byte word, it must be '110xxxxx 10xxxxxx', three-byte word:'1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx', four-byte word:'11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx', right? So we did a lot to identify the words in the world, my question is, when I try to print char from 128-159, why all the result is '?' ?